# Partitioning for Dual Boot Windows 8.1/ Ubuntu HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, system-installation

So i got a blank 750 GB HDD on a laptop. My intention is to install Windows 8.1 only on a single partion like a 100 GB for the system only to use it for my university programs etc. and to use Ubuntu for personal use like browsing, listening to music. For example Windows 8 to be only 100 GB and the other free space to be for Ubuntu and i know Ubuntu has to be on separate partiotions like the swap, / (root), /home. Can you tell me how to do it or a walkthrough?

Comment: New system with UEFI or older system with only BIOS. Or with UEFI you can install in BIOS mode? Install is a lot different for UEFI or BIOS. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system OR: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic, but needs to be asked: why dual boot if you're only using windows for school? Installing windows in a VM allows you to access windows any time and removes all the issues with uefi/secure boot and the rest.